# RxSwift table view with multiple custom cell types

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2, rx-swift

I'w wonder is there any code example for `RxSwift` when I can use multiple custom cells inside one table view. So for example I have two section and first section has 10 cells with type `CellWithImage` identifier and second section has 10 cells with type `CellWithVideo` identifier.

All tuts and code examples which I've founded are using only one cell type, for instance [RxSwiftTableViewExample](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxExample/RxExample/Examples/SimpleTableViewExample/SimpleTableViewExampleViewController.swift)

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've managed it using [RxSwiftDataSources](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxDataSources),

it allow you to use custom cells with multi sections.
[I've used this code for help](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxDataSources/blob/master/Examples/Example/Example4_DifferentSectionAndItemTypes.swift)

Comment: can you share the code how how you implemented this after all?

Comment: is it ? we can't add other table function directly with RxSwift?

Answer (score 19):

You can set multiple custom cell without RxDatasource.

```
    //Register Cells as you want
    tableView.register(CustomRxTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "BasicCell")



    ViewModel.data.bind(to: tableView.rx.items){(tv, row, item) -> UITableViewCell in

        if row == 0 {
            let cell = tv.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BasicCell", for: IndexPath.init(row: row, section: 0))

            cell.textLabel?.text = item.birthday
            return cell
        }else{
            let cell = tv.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: IndexPath.init(row: row, section: 0)) as! CustomRxTableViewCell
            cell.titleLb.text = item.name
            return cell
        }

    }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 5):

In case anybody's interested, here's my implementation. I have an app with a list of games. Depending if the game is finished or still on going i use different cells. Here's my code:

In the ViewModel, I have a list of game, split them into finished/ongoing ones and map them to `SectionModel`

```
let gameSections = PublishSubject<[SectionModel<String, Game>]>()
let dataSource = RxTableViewSectionedReloadDataSource<SectionModel<String, Game>>()

...

self.games.asObservable().map {[weak self] (games: [Game]) -> [SectionModel<String, Game>] in
    guard let safeSelf = self else {return []}
    safeSelf.ongoingGames = games.filter({$0.status != .finished})
    safeSelf.finishedGames = games.filter({$0.status == .finished})
    
    return [SectionModel(model: "Ongoing", items: safeSelf.ongoingGames), SectionModel(model: "Finished", items: safeSelf.finishedGames)]
}.bindTo(gameSections).addDisposableTo(bag)
```

Then in the ViewController, I bind my sections to my tableview, and use different cells like this. Note that I could use the indexPath to get the right cell instead of the status.

```
vm.gameSections.asObservable().bindTo(tableView.rx.items(dataSource: vm.dataSource)).addDisposableTo(bag)
vm.dataSource.configureCell = {[weak self] (datasource, tableview, indexpath, item) -> UITableViewCell in
    if item.status == .finished {
        let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FinishedGameCell", for: indexpath) as! FinishedGameCell
        cell.nameLabel.text = item.opponent.shortName
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OnGoingGameCell", for: indexpath) as! OnGoingGameCell
        cell.titleLabel.text = item.opponent.shortName
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: How could you update an item in the data source? `dataSource.sectionModels` is get-only. My model is an array and im trying to update one of the items after some user input. Thanks