# RxSwift TableView - How to set numberOfRowsInSection?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

Using RxSwift, is there an equivalent to numberOfRowsInSection? It seems like Rx automatically sets the amount of rows based on the data, but I need to add an additional unique cell at the end of the tableview that doesn't relate to the data. Since the tableView returns automatically once it's gone through all the data, I can't set that cell. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should make UI manipulations through your data. Anyway, I suggest checking out `RxDataSources`: https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxDataSources

Also please check out this question:
[RxSwift table view with multiple custom cell types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39079491/rxswift-table-view-with-multiple-custom-cell-types)